# If $\mathcal{A}$ is a closed subalgebra of $C(X, \mathbb{R})$, then $|f| \in \mathcal{A}$ whenever $f \in \mathcal{A}$, and $\mathcal{A}$ is a lattice

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

In Folland's text he gives the following lemma where $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $\|\cdot\|_u$ dentoes the uniform metric:

> 1. If $\mathcal{A}$ is a closed subalgebra of $C(X, \mathbb{R})$, then $|f| \in \mathcal{A}$ whenever $f \in \mathcal{A}$, and $\mathcal{A}$ is a lattice.

He precedes this by another lemma:

> 2. For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a polynomial $P$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $P(0) = 0$ and $\big\vert |x| - P(x)\big\vert < \epsilon$ for $x \in [-1, 1]$.

The proof he provides for Lemma 1 is as follows:

> If $f \in \mathcal{A}$ and $f \neq 0$, let $h = f/\|f\|_u$. Then $h$ maps $X$ into $[-1, 1]$, so if $\epsilon > 0$ and $P$ as in Lemma 2, we have $\|~|h| - P \circ h \|_u < \epsilon$. Since $P(0) = 0$, $P$ has no constant term, so $P \circ h \in \mathcal{A}$ since $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra. Since $\mathcal{A}$ is closed and $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we have $|h| \in \mathcal{A}$ and hence $|f| = \|f\|_u |h| \in \mathcal{A}$. This proves the first assertion, and the second one follows because
> $$ \max(f,g) = \frac{1}{2}(f + g + |f-g|), \quad \min(f,g) = \frac{1}{2}(f + g - |f-g|).$$

Here I am confused on why $P$ not containing a constant term implies $P \circ h \in \mathcal{A}$? Also to show that $|h| \in \mathcal{A}$ are we considering a sequence constructed by polynomials (depending on $\epsilon$) which converge to $|h|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P(t)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} c_kt^{k}$ the $P(h)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} c_kh^{k}$. Since $\mathcal A$ is an algebra all powers of $h$ are in  it and so are their linear combinations.

If $(P_n(x))$ is a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to $|x|$ then $P_n(h) \to |h|$ and each $P_n(f)$ is in $\mathcal A$. Since $\mathcal A$ is closed we see that $|h|\in \mathcal A$.

[ $\epsilon =\frac  1n$ in the Lemma shows existence of  a polynomial $P_n$ such that $|P_n(x)-|x|| <\frac  1n$ for all $n,x$. Note that $P_n(x) \to |x|$ uniformly].